# Variables in Main Class

Tags: java, program-entry-point

So I am programming the game War, and I need to put all of the methods in the main class. I am having trouble initializing the variables due to some errors.

```
public class Main {
    public Player<Card> player1 = new Player<Card>();
    public Player<Card> player2 = new Player<Card>(); 
    public Player<Card>[] players = new Player[2];
    players[0] = player1;
    players[1] = player2;
public static void main(String[] args) {



 }


}
```

In those lines of code, after I make the array, I get an error that says: 
"Multiple markers at this line

- Type safety: The expression of type Player[] needs unchecked conversion to conform to     Player[]
- Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token"

The Player class is extending a stack of type Card.
Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not `public Player<Card>[] players = new Player<Card>[2];` ? Also I do not think you're supposed to be initializing members inside the class.

Comment: When I do public Player<Card>[] players = new Player<Card>[2]; 
I get this error: "- Cannot create a generic array of Player<Card>"

Comment: Definitely these two statements shouldn't be there: `players[0] = player1;
    players[1] = player2;`.

Comment: ya i got help, thank you guys

Answer (score 4):

Statements such as

```
players[0] = player1;
players[1] = player2;
```

can't be done outside of a method or constructor.

You can put them in the constructor :

```
public Main () {
    players[0] = player1;
    players[1] = player2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an initializer block if you want to do it outside of Main:

```
class Main {
    public Player<Card> player1 = new Player<Card>();
    public Player<Card> player2 = new Player<Card>();
    public Player<Card>[] players = new Player[2];

    {
        players[0] = player1;
        players[1] = player2;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
}
```

Or alternatively, provide a constructor and initialize the instance variables (players/1/2) in that constructor.

Comment: So I did this, and now the error is no longer a red light bulb, but continues to be a yellow lightbulb saying: "Type safety: The expression of type Player[] needs unchecked conversion to conform to Player[]"
Will this affect my code?

Comment: @stephcurry that's weird, I tried running this code both using Java 7 & Java 8 and I didn't get this warning. Assuming that the case is exactly as mentioned above you can safely ignore it, and if needed, use `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use a static block in the class if you are not going to initialize variables in constructor, you have to make variables static and try

```
static {
      players[0] = player1;
      players[1] = player2;
 }
```